# Quickblox: Get list of Custom Object classes

Tags: quickblox

When using the 'Custom Module', is there an API to get a list of all classes?

As new classes may be added from time to time through the admin panel, the app will need to dynamically retrieve all classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standart API to do this, but you can create class e.g. 'MyClass' and store all classes in it. Will work like what you need.

Comment: Is there any way we can create class dynamically using App iOS SDK?

Comment: No, there isn't at the moment. Do you think it will be a good choice for developers?

Comment: Yes, Currently we are storing our chat history in one class So all thousands of conversations in one class So if we execute any query it will look up in one class which contains thousands of records. So it may take more time to load. If we can create class dynamically then we can create classes user wise so if we want to access conversation of one user simply just need to query for that class.

Comment: @IgorKhomenko we have requirement of adding class dynamically per user using api from iOS sdk. Please let me know if this support available. looking forward to hear from you.